# How to completely uninstall Blender?

Tags: blender

I installed Blender 2.79, but I want to install Blender 2.80. How can I uninstall it?

[image: screenshot of terminal]

Comment: Hello and Wellcome to askubuntu. Your question depens how you installed Blender. Can you please enter `apt list blender*` into your terminal and copy the output into your question?

Comment: no matches found: blender*

Comment: How did you install Blender? It seems you dont have it from the Software Store, neither you downlaoded a .deb file.

Comment: I installed it in opt.

Comment: Did you compiled it yourself? Did you follow a instruction?

Comment: $ tar -xjf blender-*-x86_64.tar.bz2
$ sudo mkdir /opt/blender
$ sudo cp -r blender-*-x86_64/* /opt/blender

Answer (score 8):

If you installed from snap, run:

```
sudo snap remove blender
```

If you installed from PPA, run:

```
sudo apt-get remove --autoremove blender
```

Edit: if you installed in /opt as you describe, run:

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/blender
```

When you install 2.8, you may wish to install with a package manager so it automatically updates:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:thomas-schiex/blender
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install blender
```

Comment: I seem to have installed it in opt

Answer (score 1):

If you installed Blender like that:

```
tar -xjf blender--x86_64.tar.bz2
sudo mkdir /opt/blender
sudo cp -r blender--x86_64/* /opt/blender
```

Then you can just move the old version into an other directory:

```
sudo mv /opt/blender ~/blender_279
```

Then you can install the beta version via snap, so you get automatically the newest blender versions:

```
sudo snap install blender --beta
```

If you want to download and install blender by hand, you can still use your old method and download the new one: https://builder.blender.org/download/ and repeat the installation (extraction and copy the files to /opt/blender)